# error when using the flutter url_launcher: ^5.4.2 i get G:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link

Tags: android, flutter

When I add the `url_launcher: ^5.4.2` to my `pubspec.yaml` and I run my flutter app.

Then I get this error:

```
> /G:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link.dart:85:21:
> Error: Method not found: 'SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated'.
>     SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated(location: routeName);
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /G:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link.dart:108:12:
> Error: Getter not found: 'Router'.
>     return Router.of(context) != null;
>            ^^^^^^
```

And my flutter version is :

```
Flutter 1.22.0 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7ec2d360bc (11 months ago) • 2020-07-29 23:25:38 -0700
Engine • revision a9910e409c
Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-1.0.dev 24c7666def)
```

Comment: try to use the last version of the package

Comment: @Fatimaayaa does not matter i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your flutter sdk I think.

My flutter version shows 2.0.6 and new version than this is also available.

Latest version of url_launcher is: **url_launcher 6.0.6**

So update this two things first this might solve your problem.

**How to upgrade flutter sdk? (Run these commands in terminal)**

```
$ flutter channel dev
$ flutter upgrade
```

**You can install latest sdk directly using:**

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
```

I have installed url_launcher 6.0.6 version and app is running fine, here is my flutter sdk details:

```
Flutter 2.0.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1d9032c7e1 (7 weeks ago) • 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
Engine • revision 05e680e202
Tools • Dart 2.12.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 ) **Lower down the library version to somewhere like 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.2, 5.7.4, 5.7.5**
NOTE :- If you still face the issue
Go to this directory `/G:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`
and `delete url_launcher_platform_interface`
Then run **flutter clean** then **flutter pub get**

Solution 2 ) **Update your SDK to Latest to use latest library in your project**

**DOING THIS ALONE MIGHT SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM**
Go to this directory `/G:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`
and `delete url_launcher_platform_interface`
Then run **flutter clean** then **flutter pub get**